# DbContext object VS alive SQL server connections

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

IMPORTANT FIRST SPEC: I need to be able to support AS MANY avalaible connections to the SQL server as possible. Ex: 200 sql connections supported but many thousands of users using the website.

Let's say I have a controller X with a property like this one --> private DataAccess.XEntities db = new DataAccess.XEntities();

Is this DBcontext object will keep open and keep a connection to the sql server alive? (I mean use 1 connection)

OR

Is it better to instanciate the DBcontext in every methods instead AND when the code has complete then it is automatically disposed therefore free a connection to the database?

My example/he way i do it right now:

```
[Authorize]
public class PrController : BaseController
{
```

GenDataAccess.GenEntities db = new GenDataAccess.GenEntities();

....

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Search()
{
    string st = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["lastSearchTerm"];
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["lastSortBy"] = null;

    int pageNumber = 1;
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["lastSearchPage"] != null)
        pageNumber = (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["lastSearchPage"];

    var now = DateTime.Now;

    var products = db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductDescription.Contains(st) || p.ProductName.Contains(st))
                              .Where(p => p.ProductExpirationDate > now)        //* exclude all expired ads
                              .Where(p => p.ProductStatusCode != "I")           //* exclude all inactive
                              .OrderByDescending(p => p.ProductExpirationDate)  //* all the newest ads first
                              .Take(1000);
```

Comment: As with almost any production system its always best to have a polling mechanism instead of opening and closing the connection every time. But for this you don't need to do anything special in DbContext, you only need to specify this in the connection string you use to initialize the DbContext object.

Comment: Refer the connection string property for polling options, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: <add name="GenEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/GenEF.csdl|res://*/GenEF.ssdl|res://*/GenEF.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=C:\GenRWD\Gen\App_Data\GenCom.mdf;initial catalog=GenComDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but is the BEST practice would be that i use: using(dbcontext cbt ..) and then perform database operation inside every method instead of having a high level reference to a dbcontext object? i need to make every user has access to the DB. The current connections pool limit is 200...

Comment: ? Is my question clear ? as per the last comment, simply give a YES/NO regards,

Comment: Yes @Martin, that is the preferrable way to use.

Comment: i have converted my code to use using block and even call db.dispose() to make sure the connections and memory gets 100% freed. thank you